# Gulp is adding \r\n instead of just \n

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, gulp, minify

I'm running a gulp task that is minifying a couple of css and JS files. It is also creating source map files at the same time.

In the source maps, it is escaping line endings as `\r\n` and I want it to escape them as `\n`.

I have this issue both on my Mac and Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this problem by using [gulp-frep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-frep)

In your `gulpfile.js` make a pattern like this:

```
var pattern = [
   {
      pattern: /\\r\\n/g,
      replacement: '\\n'
    }
];
```

And then just run gulp-frep **after writing of sourcemaps** `sourcemaps.write('.')`.

Additionally better to filter your stream files to *apply replacement only to sourcemaps* (for example with [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if)).

Here is an example:

```
var pattern = [
   {
      pattern: /\\r\\n/g,
      replacement: '\\n'
    }
];

gulp.task('projectJS', function() {
return gulp.src('pathToJS/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.map', frep(pattern)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./media/js/'));
});
```

The same thing with `css` files